# Python map() with cases

Tags: python, functional-programming, mapping

Simple enough but I can't find a decent example; so I asked here!

Basically what I was is, resultList = map(if >0:do this, else:do this, listOfNumbers)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `lambda` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)) function. I've used placeholder functions `foo()` and `bar()` which you'll have to replace with your "do this" / "do that" bits.

```
resultList = map(lambda x: foo(x) if x > 0 else bar(x), listOfNumbers)
```

An alternative, which as @hop rightfully says is the preferred method in Python, is to use a list comprehension. This doesn't even need the use of a `lambda` function.

```
resultList = [foo(x) if x > 0 else bar(x) for x in listOfNumbers)
```

Comment: a list comprehension or generator expression is preferrable nowadays

Comment: as per the guidelines I make a habit of waiting 2 days to accept answers, and by your flair you weren't in desperate need of immediate points! :D Cheers

Comment: @Andrew Bolster Was just doing a scan through all answered questions w/o any accepted answer and commenting on them. I'll keep the 2 day window in mind in future, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple: DON'T TO THIS.

Really. Be friendly to those guy who have to read code after you. Write it in few lines, like that:

```
def choose_value(x):
  if x > 0:
    return blah(x)
  return minor(x)

results = map(choose_value, list_of_numbers)
```

This is much more readable and reusable on my taste.

Comment: Aigh. The list comprehension seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
resultList = [foo(x) if x > 0 else bar(x) for x in listOfNumbers]
```